# Spring Security Webflux. How to make ServerWebExchange return pre-authentication Principal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I cannot access the `java.security.Principal` authenticated by my CAS authentication system. `serverWebExchange.getPrincipal()` is allways empty.

In fact this is the implementation of [`DefaultServerWebExchange`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/adapter/DefaultServerWebExchange.html) :

```
@Override
public <T extends Principal> Mono<T> getPrincipal() {
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

Another implementation of [`ServerWebExchange`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ServerWebExchange.html) is [`ServerWebExchangeDecorator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ServerWebExchangeDecorator.html) and its documentation says:

> Note: if the purpose for using a decorator is to override properties
>   like `getPrincipal()`, consider using `ServerWebExchange.mutate()`
>   instead.

So my **first question** is: If that is what I am supposed to do, at what point in my WebFlux Security configuration (below) am I supposed to use `ServerWebExchange.mutate().getPrincipal()` to override `ServerWebExchange.getPrincipal()`?

My **second question** is: How am I supposed to get the pre-authenticated non-reactive request Principal?

So far, the only way I have found to retrieve the request Principal from [`ServerWebExchange`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ServerWebExchange.html) is using reflection. But obviously that is not what I am supposed to do.

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig {
@Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .logout().disable()

                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager())
                .securityContextRepository(this.securityContextRepository())
                .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeExchange().anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and().build();
    }

    @Bean
    ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return authentication -> {
            log.debug("Autentication: " + authentication.toString());
            if (authentication instanceof CustomPreAuthenticationToken) {
                authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
            }

            return Mono.just(authentication);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    ServerSecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
        return new ServerSecurityContextRepository() {
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> save(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, SecurityContext securityContext) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
                Principal nonReactivePrincipal = getPrincipalFromExchangeUsingReflection(serverWebExchange);

            return Mono.just(new SecurityContextImpl(new CustomPreAuthenticationToken(nonReactivePrincipal.getName(), nonReactivePrincipal,  AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER") )));
            }
        };
    }


    private Principal getPrincipalFromExchangeUsingReflection(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
        Principal principal = null;

        try {
            Field ServletServerHttpRequestField = serverWebExchange.getClass().getDeclaredField("request");
            ServletServerHttpRequestField.setAccessible(true);
            Object servletServerHttpRequest = ServletServerHttpRequestField.get(serverWebExchange);
            Field httpServletRequestField = servletServerHttpRequest.getClass().getDeclaredField("request");
            httpServletRequestField.setAccessible(true);
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) httpServletRequestField.get(servletServerHttpRequest);

            principal = httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal();

        } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return principal;
    }
}



public class CustomPreAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {        
    public CustomPreAuthenticationToken(String key, Object principal, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(key, principal, authorities);
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems like for webflux the way to access principals looks like following: `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map { sc -> sc.authentication.principals}` so there is a special holder which returns you reactive security context with authentication and principals. Out of the box there is no place where someone calls `ServerWebExchange.mutate()`

Comment: @ashirman is right. It is also described in the release notes of 5 RC 1: https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released

Comment: In reply to @ashirma and Tobske. 
This is a pre-authenticated scenario. The request is authenticated by the container. There is no principal in the SecurityContext. Actually, that is what I need to do, retrieve the principal from the server exchange request and put it in the Security Context

Comment: ok, seems like I misunderstood `pre-authenticated non-reactive request Principal`. Please take a look following classes `SecurityContextServerWebExchange`, `SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter` and `AuthenticationWebFilter`.You can create a wrapper above ServerWebExchange and override method ` getPrincipal()` properly.If existing `SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter`  can't be used with your CAS auth system feel free to register your own filter and save Principals into reactive context to get them later.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @dcg, we gave up on Webflux. To many problems with our infrastructure, RPM and CAS authentication system. In any case, the fact that there were no replies to this question, nor more upvotes, probably means that we were either "fighting the framework" or going down the wrong road