# Get jwt-claims in a stateless spring-webflux service

Tags: java, jwt, spring-webflux

Is there an easy way to pick up a jwt-claim in an endpoint built via swagger for a stateless spring-webflux-resource-service without having to manually pick the token from the header and parse it again as it is already done by the framework?

The method definition is similar to this (generated via `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`):

```java
@Validated
@Api(value = "seller", description = "the seller API")
public interface SellerApi {

    @ApiOperation(value = "gets all pricing models for sellers", nickname = "sellerPricingModels", notes = "provides a list of pricing models for the sellers", response = RestPricingModel.class, responseContainer = "List", tags={ "seller","pricing-models", })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "picked up all the pricing models from the database", response = RestPricingModel.class, responseContainer = "List"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "unauthorized", response = RestErrorBody.class) })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/seller/pricing-models",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    default Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<RestPricingModel>>> sellerPricingModels(@ApiParam(value = "" ,required=true) @RequestHeader(value="Language-Code", required=true) String languageCode, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        Mono<Void> result = Mono.empty();
        exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
        ...
        return result.then(Mono.empty());

    }

}
```

I am using as authentication provider `auth0` and I am testing it using their downloadable angular sample. I authenticated myself, I can see the token with the correct claims in `auth0` debugging console, I can see the claims loaded fine in my test-ui but I am stuck fetching the claims from the token.

What I am trying to do is to have this stateless service and when an authenticated user tries to access an endpoint (i.e. `/seller/pricing-models`), I want to fetch only resources for this user. To have this done, I need to pick the user-id from the claims. This is not impossible, but I was wondering if I use something already provided by spring. Ideally, this would be something that does not require me to modify the method as it is automatically generated or at least to configure the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` to insert it there.

Comment: the token, should of been exchanged for the principal, so there should be info there.

Comment: I am using this to check the principal: `exchange.getPrincipal().subscribe(x -> log.info("Got principal: {}", x.getName()), err -> log.error("Got error:", err), () -> log.info("No value"));` and it always goes through the `no value` branch`. I am pretty sure I am messing something in authentication, but I don't know what.

Comment: dont `subscribe` the calling client is the subscriber, your application is a `publisher`. That is basic webflux knowledge. The one initiating the call is the subscriber. and "and it always goes through the no value branch`" makes no sense, branch? what are you talking about?

Comment: I'm still getting my head around the whole reactive thing - and I just wanted to dump the value. But it seems like this whole `Principal` thing is a bit deeper than I thought: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650382/spring-security-webflux-how-to-make-serverwebexchange-return-pre-authentication.

Comment: You probably want to integrate with the spring OAuth2 stuff, which integrates with spring security. Parse your jwt into a JwtAuthenticationToken and then it's the standard @PreAuthorize("hasRole('role_admin')"), etc.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it works fine. The problem is some endpoints need to retrieve data specific to the user. Like their private messages, let's say. For this, I need an user-id which already exists in the jwt-token. In the end, I could go decode each time the token and pick it up from there, but it's kind of cumersome. I was hoping for a more elegant way like @ThomasAndolf proposed. The thing is, the principal is empty.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf - sorry for misunderstanding. What I meant was the `subscribe` there was just for test/debug and out of the 3 choices (`x`, `err` and `no value`) it goes always via `no value`.